# Signing my Mac pkg works but installation fails?

Tags: macos, installation, certificate, signing

**I'm signing my mac package using this commandline:**

```
Volumes/Auxiliary\ Tools/PackageMaker.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageMaker \
--sign /Users/company/src/clients/linux-client/mac/company_client_installer.pkg \
--certificate "Developer ID Application: company"
```

**Signing works, but installation fails with error. This is the relevant part in the install.log:**

```
Oct 16 16:59:33 mac installd[57355]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=102 "The package “company_client_installer.pkg” is untrusted." UserInfo=0x106a2be30 {NSLocalizedDescription=The package “company_client_installer.pkg” is untrusted., NSURL=file://localhost/Users/company/src/clients/linux-client/mac/company_client_installer.pkg#companyClient.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.company.company_client_installer.pkg, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ffd2a52c900 "The operation couldn’t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED"} {
1674             NSLocalizedDescription = "The package \U201ccompany_client_installer.pkg\U201d is untrusted.";
1675             NSURL = "file://localhost/Users/company/src/clients/linux-client/mac/company_client_installer.pkg#companyClient.pkg";
1676             NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-2147409622 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED\" UserInfo=0x7ff     d2a5573b0 {SecTrustResult=5, PKTrustLevel=PKTrustLevelNotTrusted, NSLocalizedFailureReason=CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED}";
1677             PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "com.company.company_client_installer.pkg";
```

**If I check the signature using pkgutil, it return:**

```
pkgutil --check-signature company_client_installer.pkg
Package "company_client_installer.pkg":
  Status: signed by a certificate trusted by Mac OS X
  Certificate Chain:
    1. Developer ID Application: company
    2. Developer ID Certification Authority
    3. Apple Root CA
```

I try'd to evaluate my certificate in "Keychain Access" and it reports "**no root cert found**" but indicates the certificate as "**valid**" with green checkmark.

I'm totally confused now. What am I'm doing wrong here? Any idea?

Volker

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find out why it was acting this way?

Comment: Puh, that is so long ago (8 years). I think it might have been the missing notarization? Don't know any more. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your error, however, I know you need to use the Developer ID Installer certificate for signing your package.

Here's the command I use :

productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: ACME, Inc (ABCDEFGHIJK)" source.pkg destination.pkg

You can also verify your package using following command :

spctl -a -vvvv --type install MyInstaller.pkg

Comment: Puh, that is so long ago (8 years). I think it might have been the missing notarization? Don't know any more. Sorry.